# Получение номера телефона при помощи авторизации через telegram

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

Использую библиотеку django-telegram-login для авторизации на сайте через telegram. Как можно получить номер телефона после авторизации? После авторизации телеграм возвращает id пользователя, фамилию и имя, фотографию. Может можно как-то через id узнать номер

Comment: вам надо узнать свой собственный номер телефона?